# How to use search button for gridview

Tags: php, search, gridview, filter, yii2

Sorry for my english!!
I need your help. I wantto make filtering and search by clicking on button. So, first, I enter a name or age, or both, and then click on the button, and table appears with data that has already been filtered.If all fields are empty and the button is not pressed, then the table should not be visible. The table appears only after clicking. (I'm using database)

Here's my fields for filter and button:

```
<div class="search">
<?php
echo $form->field($data, 'name')->textInput();
echo $form->field($data, 'age')->textInput();
?>
</div>
<?= Html::submitButton('search'); ?>
```

And my gridview:

```
<div class="gridview">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'name',
                'age',
        ]); ?>
    </div>
```

What i need to write in my controller? I don't understand, i really want to get it!!
Thanks everyone for your attention!!

Comment: You can use `JQuery` to hide gridview if fields are empty.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco thanks, got it. And what about search by click? :(

Comment: What you mean by `And what about search by click` ?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco well when i click i search data with filter

Answer (score 0):

> And what about search by click?

To search out of the GridView you should make like this searching form:

```
<div class="search">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
     'action' => ['index'],
     'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($data, 'name') ?>

<?= $form->field($data, 'age') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you get the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me (i'm new at Yii2, sorry for stupid questions) how to use input value after submit form? For example I write name in field "Bob", submit form, and i dont know how to get this name after that, i want to use it in another view

Comment: I showed you a search form. You should have a `model` named something like `SearchModel` where you have properties set up. Take a look here: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview. There are a lot of resources where you can get needed information, make a research.

Comment: thank you again :) but it wasnt for search, i mean i want use value from input after submit, for example, to show in another form "Hello, my name is *name from field* Bob". I was asking about that :))))

Comment: You can get thous using `Yii::$app->request->get()` method as far as you make a `get` request.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a multidimensional array of search fields in the controller using the method `Yii::$app->request->queryParams` Or `Yii::$app->request->get()`

Also to check and not display the table before searching: (or send blank field)

1. Create your own gridview and search page using the **Gii** tool (CRUD Generator)
2. Then add the required codes (**for example**)

**View File**

```
    <div class="search">
      <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
           'action' => ['index'],
           'method' => 'get',
      ]); ?>
    
      <?= $form->field($data, 'name') ?>
      <?= $form->field($data, 'age') ?>

      <div class="form-group">
          <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
      </div>
    
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>


    <?php if ($show === true): ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'name',
                'age',
         ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

**Controller(Index action)**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    # code...
       
    // Yii::$app->request->queryParams['YourModelSearch'] Or ...
    $get_model = current(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        // Check in whichever way you prefer
        'show' => (!empty($get_model['name']) or !empty($get_model['age'])) ? true : false,
    ]);
}
```

You can also use JQuery.